# Selenium IDE-Automating Select2 Search Box

Tags: selenium, ide, jquery-select2

I am trying to automate the select2 search box in selenium IDE.
I got it to open and also typed the search keyword I am searching for.However even though I have the code in place for showing results, it does not work. The problem is I guess the characters are getting typed too fast, so the results don't show up for the search box. I am sure I am going wrong somewhere, because I am new to Selenium IDE .So any help is appreciated

```
  mouseDown css=.select2-choice > div > b
  type css=input.select2-input.select2-focused Chris
  waitForVisible css=.select2-results
  mouseUp css=.select2-result-label:contains('Chris')
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had to deal with this as well, the sites I test use select2 and select3.   What I've found that works in both situations would be the following:

```
clickAt | css=.select2-choice > div > b | 
sendKeys | css=input.select2-input.select2-focused | Chris
click | css=.select2-result-label:contains('Chris')
```

With these types of dropdowns, and Angular, I found sendKeys works better than type or typeKeys.

Klendathu

Comment: It worked for me when modified slightly - same first step; sendKeys | css=#select2-drop input.select2-input | Chris ; same last step but with clickAt rather than click