# Selenium IDE select2 selecting an item

Tags: selenium, ide, jquery-select2

Pretty new to selenium IDE.

I've been trying to get this to work but I have some issues with select2.
I've looked into other issues like:[Selenium IDE-Automating Select2 Search Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091053/selenium-ide-automating-select2-search-box?answertab=votes#tab-top) 
etc..

What I have so far is:

```
clickAt | css=.select2-choice |
sendKeys | css=#select2-drop input.select2-input | Adobe
clickAt | css=.select2-result-label:contains('Adobe') |
```

It opens the select2, types ' Adobe ' and filters, but it won't click on the result it finds.
Any ideas/suggestions?

Kind regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
clickAt | css=.select2-choice |
sendKeys | css=#select2-drop input.select2-input | Adobe
pause | 1000
clickAt | css=.select2-result-label:contains('Adobe') |
```

This fixed it, putting a pause in the middle. It went to fast, if you put Selenium on ' Slow mode ' it went fine, just on fast it sweeped over it.

Answer (score 6):

I think is better  without "pause" (performance)

```
clickAt | css=.select2-choice |  
sendKeys | css=#select2-drop input.select2-input | Adobe   
waitForVisible | css=#select2-drop |  
clickAt | css=.select2-result-label:contains('Adobe') |
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way

Ruby code:

```js
element = @browser.element(:xpath => '//xpath/to/a.select2-choice')
element.focus
@browser.send_keys [:shift, :tab]
@browser.send_keys :tab
@browser.send_keys :arrow_down
```